Accessing environment variables from Pod container in Kubernetes
When needing to use environment variables in my React code, I usually follow the path of using the .env file and by using process.env in my code to access those variables.  However, when deploying my docker image to the Kubernetes environment inside the Pod container, the .env file is not used.  So now what do I do?
The IT team managing the K8s environment said that they can define an env variable on the Pod for me to use... great!  My goal is to have a different API URL for each environment (dev, qa, prod)
So, the YAML looks like this...
containers:
    - name: audit-webapp
      image: blahartifacts.azurecr.io/audit/blahauditwebapp:1.0.850
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 5004
          protocol: TCP
      env:
        - name: ROOT_API_URL
          value: https://dev.blah.org/api

Not sure how to exploit those environment vars but I started just using the same process.env object to retrieve those values inside my deployed React app in the Pod...
console.log("ROOT_API_URL:" + process.env.ROOT_API_URL)

Here is the output: ROOT_API_URL:undefined
I'm probably missing something obvious here.  Maybe I need to build env vars in my Docker image? (But then, I'd have to have a separate docker image per environment (dev, qa, prod))  Any help is much appreciated!
So far, I've tried using the 'env: key/value pairs' as defined in the YAML in the Pod container creation as built by the IT team.  Was hoping the process.env object would have scope to the Pod container environment vars but it does not seem to.  Maybe there is some prefix?... _ROOT_API_URL ?
